# Python - Flask API - TCP Socket concurrency

Tags: python, sockets, asynchronous, flask, concurrency

I would like to build a Python Flask-based API that returns data based on this API's communication with several servers over TCP sockets.

It is clear that the API will need to do several things are once:

- Serve responses to incoming HTTP requests
- Communicate with several servers via TCP **socket** module, sending and receiving data

What Python architecture should I choose, based on your experience?

- Can I combine Flask API service and the part of the application doing the socket comms in one process, or would there be concurrency issues?
- If not, what is the best solution in this case?

N.B. This is not a *broad architectural question*. This is a very specific question about Python Flask and how it would work with TCP sockets module.

EDIT:
In Python, TCP sockets can be blocking and non-blocking, which obviously interferes with the functionality of a web-server. Hence my question about the best way of integrating both together: in a single process vs two separate processes.

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to implement it?

Comment: Whether two pieces of code are in one module or in separate modules is unrelated to whether there are concurrency issues. (So yes, you can combine them.)

Comment: @mkrieger1 my apologies, I have been sloppy with the terminology. Not "modules", of course. I meant a python process. One issue that I can immediately foresee is that a socket wait receive is a blocking call. If implemented incorrectly it would block the web server, wouldn't it? I think this is a valid question